# $X,Y$ be NLS , $T:X \to Y$ be a linear map such that $T^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed for every $y \in Y$ and $T$ has closed graph , then is $T$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X,Y$ be NLS , $T:X \to Y$ be a linear map such that $T^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed for every $y \in Y$ and $T$ has closed graph , then is it true that $T$ is continuous ?

I know that the statement is true if $Y$ is finite dimensional because in that case $\ker T$ closed implies continuity of $T$  , and I also know that if $X,Y$ are Banach spaces then it is true by closed graph theorem . But I don't know what happens in general  . Since $T$ has closed graph , I know that $T$ maps compact sets to closed sets ; for general metric spaces I know that a function having closed graph and carrying compact sets to "compact "sets must be continuous , so it seems we are very close . Though for $\mathbb R$ and only maps ( not linear ) the statement is false as can be seen from $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)=1/x , \forall  x\ne 0 ; f(0)=0$

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be any injective bounded linear operator of Banach spaces $Y \to Z$ such that $S(Y)$ is not closed, take $X = S(Y)$ (with the norm of $Z$) and 
$T = S^{-1}$.

Comment: In don't think it is clear why the graph of $T$ needs to be closed in this case.

Comment: The graph of $T$ is a continuous image of the graph of $S$, and the graph of a bounded linear operator is closed.  Or more explicitly:
If $(x_n,y_n)$ are in the graph of $T$, i.e. $x_n = S y_n$, and $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$, then since $y_n \to y$ we have $x_n = S(y_n) \to S(y)$, and thus $x = S(y)$, so $(x,y)$ is in the graph of $T$.